# Angular ViewChild undefined if child extends base class

Tags: angular, typescript, oop, components, extend

I started with four components:

- `UserListComponent`
- `UserSearchComponent`
- `GroupListComponent`
- `GroupSearchComponent`

Both list components reference their corresponding search component via a `ViewChild` decorated property.  For example, the `UserListComponent` has a property defined like:

```js
@ViewChild(UserSearchComponent)
userSearch: UserSearchComponent;
```

The two list components and search components were so similar with each other, I started looking into how to have components extend base classes so that I **D**id not **R**epeat **M**yself.  I started by creating a base class for the search components with the following declaration:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'td-search',
  template: ''
})
export class SearchComponent<T> {
  ...
}
```

Once I extended the two search components, my `ViewChild` references, in both cases, ended up returning `undefined`.  For example, here is the `UserSearchComponent`'s declaration after introducing the base class:

```js
export class UserSearchComponent extends SearchComponent<UserSearch> {
```

`UserSearch` is just a class that wraps available search parameters as an object/payload to send off to the server.

So the `ViewChild` properties work in both cases as long as I don't have a base class for the two search components.  But as soon as I introduce a base class, I can't seem to get a `ViewChild` reference of the types of the two search components.

The error I get looks like this:
[image]

...and I'm just trying to set a property on the search component once the results come back in the list component by calling this method:

```js
private resetSearch() {
  this.loading = false;
  this.userSearch.disabled = false;
}
```

#### Question:

Can I use base classes with components I intend to use as `ViewChild` references?

#### Update:

I made the realization, too, that the `ViewChild` is NOT undefined at first... in `ngOnInit` of the `UserListComponent`, I am subscribing to a `searches` property of the `UserSearchComponent` (of type `EventEmitter<UserSearch>`).  This successfully finds the `UserSearchComponent` and I confirmed this by logging out the whole object right before making the subscription call:

```js
console.log(this.userSearch);
this.userSearch.searches.subscribe((search: UserSearch) => {
  this.loading = true;
  const params = new UserSearchQueryParams();
  params.Login = search.login;
  params.Username = search.user;
  params.EnabledOnly = search.enabled;
  this.users$ = this._users.getUsers(params).pipe(
    catchError(this.handleError),
    finalize(this.resetSearch)
  );
});
```

In the `finalize` operator of the call to `getUsers` observable, I call `resetSearch` which is where `this.userSearch` is returning undefined.  So before I do the search, the search component child reference works, but after the search takes place, the list component's child reference to the search component doesn't work...

Comment: is there a `@ViewChild` in the base class?

Comment: There is not.  The base class just gives the two search components some shared functionality but has no child components it needs to reference

Comment: Try removing the selector of the base class (assuming that each derived class has its own selector).

Comment: Cool. Then, is there a `userSeach` property defined in the base class? Also, it's a lot to ask, but if you could set up a StackBlitz with an example of this, it would be really helpful.

Comment: @ConnorsFan thanks for the suggestion!  I tried it, but see the same behavior still :(

Comment: @joh04667, the `userSearch` property is the `ViewChild` reference in the list component.  The base class does not have a property with this name

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Answer (score 0):

BUMMER, this ended up being way less interesting than I was hoping for.  In my subscriptions to the searching requests from the user, I was using the `finalize` operator on the observable that is the call to `getUsers`, and was attempting to use a method group like I can in C#:

```
this.userSearch.searches.subscribe((search: UserSearch) => {
  this.loading = true;
  const params = new UserSearchQueryParams();
  params.Login = search.login;
  params.UserName = search.user;
  params.EnabledOnly = search.enabled;
  this.users$ = this._users.getUsers(params).pipe(
    catchError(this.handleError),
    finalize(this.resetSearch)
  );
});
```

If I change the usage of the `finalize` operator to not include a method group, like so:

```
...
    finalize(() => this.resetSearch())
...
```

... then my `this.userSearch` does not return `undefined` in the body of `resetSearch`.  I've run into the issue of trying to use method groups in typescript before.  Sometimes they work, sometimes they don't, but this is a case of when they don't and I should just stop trying to use them I think...

Comment: An alternative: `finalize(this.resetSearch.bind(this))`.

Comment: Another alternative is to define `resetSearch` as an arrow function: `private resetSearch = () => {...}`.